# Application failed codesign verification: Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, flash-builder, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm trying to submit my iOS application to iTunes Connect with the Application Loader. I've tried many times using different certificates but every time I go to submit it I get a error saying "Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate." I am changing the file extension to a ".zip" then uploading a compressed version of the ".app" file. When I view the file contents it says the type of certificate is a developer provisioning profile but that even happens when I download it right from Apple's website and view it's type. I've been researching a solution for this for the past four days and I haven't found any results. I also am creating my application using Flash Builder and I have verified that I am doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To submit to the App Store, you must code sign with an App Store provisioning profile (created under Distribution on your developer account page). Your Entitlements.plist file must have it's one field "can be debugged" set to NO.

Comment: How do I check the Entitlements.plist file?

Comment: Is that found under the .app file?

Comment: Alright, I looked under the ".app" file and I haven't found a Entitlements.plist file. Could that be the problem?

Comment: If you don't readily see one in your project, create a new file of the Property List type (under resources in the new file window) and title it Entitlements.plist. Add a single field to this file in the editor and call it "Can be debugged". It is a boolean variable that should be set to NO for any distribution or shipping to the App Store.

Then, in your build settings, there is a field called Code Signing Entitlements where you must enter the file path to your Entitlements.plist file.

Comment: In Flash Builder there is a Entitlements code block that was commented out for some reason. How would I write the key for "can be debugged?" Like this? "Can-be-debugged"

Comment: Not sure, but this may only be part of your problem. You still need an App Store Distribution Provisioning profile downloaded from your Apple developer center. Also, I'm only aware of .ipa files being valid binary submission to the store.

Comment: Well, I'm going to try and build it with that key and see what happens. I have the provisioning profiles and everything, I've tried many different ones but it seems like it isn't the problem now. I'm surprised Adobe hasn't fixed these problems in Flash Builder yet. My last app I had to completely redo in xcode which required me to learn Objective-C. I really hope this works.

Comment: You said you had a Developer distribution profile, which is not an App Store Distribution profile

Comment: Would you like to discuss this in a chat? I have more information on it. When I save my Provisioning Profile to my Mac and view it in the finder it says it's "Kind" is a Developer profile.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23187/discussion-between-storm-shadows-and-patrick-goley)